# Is there a better development configuration than this?

Tags: svn, development-environment

I'm about to implement a new development configuration and before I head down the wrong path I need to know if this scenario has any pitfalls or could be optimized in any way.

I know this is somewhat open-ended, but development environments are never the same so I need eyes on this specific implementation.

**The answers I'm really looking for are specific suggestions on how to change this configuration.**

[image: Development Environment]